# Use manually linked libraries with React Native 0.61

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm upgrading from RN 0.59.4 to 0.61.4. It seems that linking dependencies via Pods is the supported method in 0.61.4. However, most of my iOS dependencies are linked manually. When building the app, I'm getting errors like React/RCTDefines.h file not found and similar errors from the libraries. What's the recommended way to approach this?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Comment: remove all manually liked libraries from xcode, do pod install then you will get all libraries, just add it

Comment: refer this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25838#issuecomment-552481681

Answer (score 0):

1. Unlink all the manually linked libraries.
2. Go to project ios folder
3. Execute `pod install`